# Apps for Windows 8 on OS < Win8

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro

When writing an app for Windows 8, what is the best way to handle things when the app is run on XP, Vista or 7?

1) Do you write two separate UIs?
2) Is it best to "window" the Metro UI (or even possible?)?
3) Is Windows 8 only 64-bit, and if so, did they get rid of the WOW stuff?

Comment: "Metro" is windows 8 only.  Windows 8 will be both 32- and 64-bit.

Comment: Use Portable Class Libraries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Metro style apps in Win 8 use a set of libraries (WinRT) which is incompatible with previous versions of windows. If you want compatibility you would have to write an app using current .NET libraries and run it in desktop mode in Win8

Comment: Or write a non-Metro application in almost anything from VB6 to plain C or even Delphi.